# Aggregation in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregate, matching

Need help with aggregation in elastic search. Is it possible to agreggate values of a particular field as an array or list - This is more of a grouping for example instead of  getting the result as

```
{"Book_Id":"102","Review_Text":"DescentRead"},{"Book_Id":"102","Review_Text":"For Kids."},{"Book_Id":"103","Review_Text":"Great"},{"Book_Id":"103","Review_Text":"Excellent"}
```

can i get all the reviews of each book as a list ?

```
 [ { Book_Id: 102, Review_Text: [ "DescentRead", "For Kids"], { Book_Id: 103, reviews: [ "Great","Excellent"] } ]
```

Tried some trail with aggs but not able to get it. Any pointers would help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could aggregations with top hits work? The limitation is that you need to specify a max amount of hits per aggregation (will return the top 100 results per book ID in the example ordered by the review text), but apart from that you can do run it as a normal query and specify which fields to return, how they should be sorted (to get the top hits), etc.

Example aggs query:

```
POST
http://myserver:9200/books/book/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "BookReviews": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "Book_Id.keyword"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top_reviews": {
          "top_hits": {
            "sort": [ { "Review_Text.keyword": { "order": "desc" } } ],
            "size": 100,
            "_source": {
              "includes": [ "Review_Text" ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that the name for the aggregations ("BookReviews" and "top_reviews") you can use any name you choose, and that same name will appear in the resulting aggregation tree. You can do multi level aggregations on terms in your index, and inclute top hits on any level, typically for drill-down reporting or similar cases.

Mapping used:

```
{
  "books": {
    "mappings": {
      "book": {
        "properties": {
          "Book_Id": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "Review_Text": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

"size": 0 in the root node will omit any hits for the search and only return the aggs trees.
You can also add a normal "query": {} block on the same level as size and aggs if you need to filter the results before elastic starts aggregating.

Read more in the elasticsearch documentation pages:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html

(If you provide a more complete example dataset, we can give a more realistic example query, as there isn't a lot of data in the example for sorting or scoring the results)

Comment: @ShabnaMt I'm not familiar with the Jest client, but it seems it can be done by building the query as a string and using the getAggregations() / getTermsAggregation methods on the result (You will have a strong dependency on the names ans the structure in the query when iterating over the result).
https://github.com/searchbox-io/Jest/blob/master/jest/src/test/java/io/searchbox/core/search/aggregation/TermsAggregationIntegrationTest.java
There may be other ways to build the query apart from just building the string yourself, but if the case is as simple as in the example, it should work as is